# How to add Posts to a Page

Tags: pages

I want to have a domain.com/blog page that includes all of my blog posts.

Problem is that currently to get to my blog, it looks like the permalink is going to always be...

domain/category/categoryname

I can change the permalinks but I dont want it to be something like domain.com/blog/featured or something.

I want to have a page that is domain/blog which will show all of my blog posts. Is there a way to do this?

My thought is simply creating a Page that includes all of my posts. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: *@jas225* - What's the URL of your blog so we can visually your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty page with blog as title.

Go to Settings -> Reading and choose *a static page* under *Front page displays*. Now set the posts page to blog that you just created and set a page that you prefer as frontpage.

I hope this whas what you were asking about, if not just let me know.

Comment: Not sure this will work as planned with my theme. Right now I'm just redirecting a static page with nothing on it using a redirect plugin to the category/blog page.

Comment: What about going to settings -> general and change your site adress to domain/blog?

Comment: *@Patrik* I think you just described on how to create a static frontpage: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page - That's not what jas225 was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible.  In my limited experience it is driven by the theme you choose.  Many themes will have a page type you can select(single post, multipost, static, archive). This way you can determine which pages have your blog posts and which do not.  You can then use the permalink settings to drive the final piece of the puzzle.  I would encourage you to look at different themes and evaluate what works for your site.  The one I use and have found flexible in this area is Atahualpa from http://wordpress.bytesforall.com/.

MM/RC

Comment: I'm using a Wootheme called OverEasy and they dont seem to have page templates for my purposes, but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You can try the plugin [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/)

This plugin allows you to list posts from a category (or categories) into a post/page using the [catlist] shortcode. You can list posts including a tag or tags also.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a shortcode?

Add the following code to your functions.php and then in your page you can add a loop with various filters

Example shortcode to put in your page: `[loop the_query="showposts=10&cat=4"]`

```
function sp_loop_shortcode($atts) {

   // Defaults
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      "the_query" => ''
   ), $atts));

   // de-funkify query
   $the_query = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $the_query);
   $the_query = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $the_query);

   // query is made               
   query_posts($the_query);

   // Reset and setup variables
   $output = '';
   $temp_title = '';
   $temp_link = '';

   // the loop
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      $temp_title = get_the_title($post->ID);
      $temp_link = get_permalink($post->ID);

      // output all findings - CUSTOMIZE TO YOUR LIKING
      $output .= "<li><a href='$temp_link'>$temp_title</a></li>";

   endwhile; else:

      $output .= "nothing found.";

   endif;

   wp_reset_query();
   return $output;

}
add_shortcode("loop", "sp_loop_shortcode");
```

I have used this method successfully on my sites.